# Can't fire commands in window with frame

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation, command

I have a WPF window with a grid containing 4 rectangles. One of these has a `<frame>` for showing pages, which is used in my application. I want to add commands to these buttons on my windows as well as to the pages.

Things I use: MVVM, Window as `Mainwindow` and Pages as contentpublisher in a frame.

For example, I want to login applicationwide with a button and command. While doing this on the page in my frame there are no errors, but I can't do the same in the window.

I was wondering if the windows lose focus so it can't fire that event while navigating to a page in the frame. So I tried to get the window with following command binding:

```
<Button Content="&#xE143;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" 
  Command="{Binding CommandWhichDoesNotFire, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type vw:MainViewModel}}}" 
  Width="32">
```

In my `ViewModel` "MainViewModel" I have a public `ICommand` Property and I initialize it at the constructor:

```
    public ICommand CommandWhichDoesNotFire;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("VM is real");

        CommandWhichDoesNotFire= new TestCommand();
    }
```

The `DataContext` of my MainView is set in the behind-code BEFORE `InitilizeComponents();`
Clicking on the button does not start ANY call of my command. It simply does not fire at all. What am I missing guys?

Comment: Could you post some more code, with minimal Window and how you set the DataContext? It is difficult to help you without it.

Comment: Are there binding errors being reported in your VS console output?  Can you run up Snoop and see whether the binding has been successful?

Answer (score 0):

You should have :

```
public ICommand CommandWhichDoesNotFire{get;set;}
public MainViewModel()
{
    MessageBox.Show("VM is real");

    CommandWhichDoesNotFire= new TestCommand(MyCommand);
}
private void MyCommand(object obj){
//Whatever you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution to your problem.
The `Frame` for some reason doesn't inherit the `DataContext` of it's parent, even if you set the `DataContext` explicitly like so:

```
DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"
```

it still doesn't work. What it does it only sets the `DataContext` of the frame but not child elements:
[image: Frame's Data Context is set]
And here is the `DataContext` of a child element:
[image: Child element Data Context is NULL!]
Now this made me think that whatever we have always loved about WPF and it's controls was the ability to inherit the `DataContext` from it's parent, with exception of `ContextMenu` and now the `Frame`. Here is the approach I took when I had a frist look at oyur problem:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainVM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <!--<local:MainVM x:Key="mainVM"/>-->
    <local:LoginPage x:Key="login" />
    <!--DataContext="{StaticResource mainVM}"-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ctrlTmpl">
        <local:LoginPage/>
    </ControlTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <!--<Button x:Name="button" Content="Do something" Click="btnDoSomething" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="221,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>-->
    <!--<Control Template="{StaticResource ctrlTmpl}"/> This works-->
    <Frame Content="{StaticResource login}" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"  />
</Grid>
```

Then I thought you can do this another way:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<!--<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainVM/>
</Window.DataContext>-->
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MainVM x:Key="mainVM"/>
    <local:LoginPage x:Key="login" DataContext="{StaticResource mainVM}"/>
    <!---->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ctrlTmpl">
        <local:LoginPage/>
    </ControlTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <!--<Button x:Name="button" Content="Do something" Click="btnDoSomething" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="221,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>-->
    <!--<Control Template="{StaticResource ctrlTmpl}"/> This works-->
    <Frame Content="{StaticResource login}"/>
</Grid>
```

Notice how I included the VM in the resources and then used that instance to be the Controls `DataContext`. At this point when I click the button in my LoginPage.xaml which by the way is a `UserControl` it triggers the Command located in my MainVM. At this point you would have to assign the `Window` `DataContext` in the code behind like so:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var vm = this.TryFindResource("mainVM");
        if(vm != null)
        {
            this.DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
```

Now at this point you can use some sort of triggers to navigate through pages and use different `Page`s or `UserControl`s. HTH
P.S. When I get a chance I will update some information about Context Menu and Frame from MSDN. Happy Coding